# Unix how to filter text file to find duplicates in part of line from 1 to 49 character and save only one

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, duplicates

I have to filter many lines of data and find duplicates in position 1-49 character. Next first duplicate stay there and else duplicates remove.
Script has to be in shell script. I read about sort, uniq but couldn't find correct example.

Duplicated lines from 1 to 49 character should be removed and save only first. 
In example row: ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z24 is duplicated by 4 times and saved only first from line 1.

I have this example of lines:

**ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z24**1

ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z215

ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z225

ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z235

**ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z24**2

**ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z24**4

**ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z24**5

Output should be:

ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z241

ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z215

ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z225

ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z235

Comment: You could go for a 2-step process, where you split the first 49 characters in the ilne, and save it in a file along with the original line. Then you could keep just the uniq columns using `uniq`. Might be slow for a large number of lines. How many lines do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind your data getting sorted first, a combination of `sort` and `awk` can be used. From a group of matching lines this will print the first line after sorting the data which is not necessarily the first line in the original file.

```
sort inputfile |awk 'BEGIN { last = ""; }
{ pattern = substr($0,1,48); if(pattern != last) print; last = pattern; }'
```

Note: I used `substr($0,1,48)` to get 48 characters because in your example I count only 48 bold characters.

With the input

```
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z241
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z215
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z225
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z235
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z242
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z244
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z245
```

I get the result

```
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z215
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z225
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z235
ALA1FZX 00013019040220180402SFOSINSFOSIN78Z78Z241
```